# Quarto extension works in example but not in my project

Tags: lua, quarto

I have created a Quarto extension to remove all occurrences of ".html" from the links. The Lua script is as follows:

```
function Link(el)
    local str = el.target
    local result = str:gsub("(.-)%.html(.-)", "%1%2")
    el.target = result
    return el
end
```

It works perfectly in the test example created within the extension. However, when I include it in my Quarto book project, it doesn't work.

The extension is being called correctly because I replaced the code with another one to format  tags with italics, and upon rendering, it worked. But when I put the above code back, it doesn't work. All links ( tags) still have ".html."

I also tried changing the order so that my filter runs after the Quarto’s built-in filters (as below), but it still didn't work.

```
filters:
  - lightbox
  - quarto
  - strip-dot-html-off
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the string replacement code, as executing `("foo-bar.html-some-more"):gsub("(.-)%.html(.-)", "%1%2")` returns `foo-bar-some-more` as expected. You haven't provided a single example as what kind of URLs you expect to modify, so maybe the issue is with something really simple (for example, using `.htm` extension instead of `.html`).

I'd check if the code works *outside* of your environment in a regular Lua interpreter and also check if you get the expected result if you set the `result` value manually to whatever result you expect from `gsub` (just to make sure that the rest of the processing happens as you envision it).

Comment: I know it's possible to achieve this by editing the Apache .htaccess file, but it would be interesting to understand why it's not working in Quarto.

The URLs are the ones that appear in the menu of a Quarto book.

I tested what you suggested... I replaced 'result' with a manual value, but it still didn't work. I also created a new Quarto book with just the default settings from "quarto create project" and then added the extension, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that Quarto might be preventing this change because, if the .htaccess file isn't configured for it, the preview wouldn't work either.

Thank you, Paulo!

Comment: I just realized that the extension is working for the links in the body of the document, that is, for the links I add in the markdown document. It just doesn't work for the navigation links, and it should be that way to avoid breaking the navigation links in the preview if you don't adjust your Apache .htaccess file.